# What is this cauliflower-like vegetable?

Tags: identification, cauliflower

My husband recently purchased this without a tag at our local nursey. We think it's some kind of cabbage plant perhaps a variant of cauliflower. Anyone know what this is?
http://postimg.org/image/nmsipq6ip/
[image]

Comment: Definitely cabbage family, not sure of the presice (cultivated) species..

Answer (score 3):

Looks like romanesco broccolli to me, and it is delicious!

Comment: and also probably the most beautiful vegetable to look at.  There are some really cool up close shots of it on the web.